# How to resolve this Forbidden error while Adding datadisk programmatically?

Tags: azure

We are consistently getting 403(forbidden) error while adding the data disk using the following [Azure REST API](https://management.core.windows.net/%3Csubscription-id%3E/services/hostedservices/%3Cservice-name%3E/deployments/%3Cdeployment-name%3E/roles/%3Crole-name%3E/DataDisks):

We used to get the 403 error when there is a problem with the management certificate, but with the same certificate all other APIs (start VM ,Stop VM etc)  are working fine. So we are not able to suspect the certificate for this error. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have a client certificate?

Comment: we created a .cer file using the "makeCert" command and uploaded the .cer file into the Azure Management portal..Please let me know whether there is any other certificate...

Comment: Can you share the code for adding the data disk? Normally 403 error means something wrong with the certificate however you mentioned that other operations are working OK so this does not look like an issue with the certificate.